# node.js to force reload require() within callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, reload

Here is the layout of my node.js scripts.

- in main.js (the caller),

  - it first `require()` a function from another file (function `a`), then
  - use function `a` for event handling
- in such event handling, is there any way to force reload function `a` in main the caller?

```js
$ head -50 *
==> a1.js <==
module.exports= function a() { return "a1" }

==> a2.js <==
module.exports= function a() { return "a2" }

==> c.js <==
const { exec } = require("child_process")

const requireReload =  modulePath => {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(modulePath)]
  return require(modulePath)
}

// show that a2 require/output is normal
let a2=require('./a2.js')
console.log(a2())

// suppose such require is defined in another file, without any exporting
let a=require('./a.js')
console.log(a())

// Now, change the content of a.js, and 
exec("ln -vsf a2.js a.js", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`)
    return
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    return
  }
  // trigger force-reloading of a.js *within a callback* in yet another file
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
  requireReload('./a.js')
  console.log("unassigned reload")
  console.log(a())
  a=requireReload('./a.js')
  console.log("assigned reload")
  console.log(a())
})
```

Here I tried to simulated my above situation in the simplest way:

- in the caller `c.js`, it first `require()` a function from another file (function `a`)
- then within the callback event handling, it tries to force reload the function `a` defined in main the caller.

But it is not working as I expected (that the content of `a=require('./a.js')` get force reloaded):

```bash
$ ln -vsf a1.js a.js
'a.js' -> 'a1.js'

$ node c.js
a2
a1
stdout: 'a.js' -> 'a2.js'

unassigned reload
a1
assigned reload
a1
```

What I'm missing?
Is there any way to force reload function `a` in main so that the output becomes `a2`?

Comment: You really ought to just rewrite your modules so they don't need to be reloaded.  Just export a function that re-initializes their state.  By default if you attempt to reload a module with `require()`, it doesn't reload, it just returns the cached module handle.  You can remove it from the cache first and it will reload, but then you will leak memory.  In ESM modules, you can never reload, so you really ought to just redesign.  This is a solvable problem with proper rewrite that doesn't need reload.

Comment: OK then. was trying to easy my debug/develop, as nodemon is not working for my specific case. Thanks for the confirmation. Will not bother spending more time on it then.